# How to render Vega-lite viz in Google Colab

Tags: altair, vega-lite

What is the recommended way of rendering a Vega-lite spec inside of Google Colab?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61802753/9124366) describes how to do this with Vega but not Vega-lite.

I've also tried this as suggested on Slack

```py
chart = alt.Chart.from_dict(vl_spec_dict)
```

However, in Colab, I get a validation error using [this valid spec](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAHJQCMlAFYQ2AOxAAaEEyRQA1mQBObBsoAmaEAHcYI9SCgqAZjTJpQSAB40IrkIKRM4QQAxFUwAZRoALzg0GQBWDT8AwQAZGgQ6WIAGHI1MOkE4EOVwqJjUeIBfRPI4Ux8kwOLS6NiEkAgATwQmNkEI1orckHzMQuaB8qqNZQYeuH0Q-WRMc0osh1toJEKfLVMABSQTExplMgBJZWUFtCzKdv2TI5OzsgB5Bkxb1Hu46o6mE6u1QoC0+h8EDKaAATFkAWQGDQTHAhP5Aj4HKFJm0EUiUfxRiDQFiSjiKu1iDsGOUQEgICZNpUAUTyiTsdDUHCNGwHA4IHBVlz4QCTEhMChQSBlEgELSxRL+AB2SQmADMcAcAE4spIkGqHHA4pIYUwtUaAGxarVxBxxRl27UgUXi+mC7xShUCFXqzU6vUGo0ms2W622+1821atAAbVAAE04EgIeg4TIZLZ7MZMB6ZGItUqefoXOgAEJsZNmDQ4BZQOoSsjlJUW6oJpMpkBpjMaLMlD0qrIwtVFksgA6GYhnOu2Gv6OslJCNtAW-5qNvJ8xpmGZox92IrrIj8zlysz2v1xflSTwtcgRMb1NZGTbnu7nNoa9iGFao-ocdsSdlGnatzwXJdUAtFtb3vDs0zVHds1zFdCxANhi2PCt9CrEBZ3nBsrxvddYKfeDX0Qj9vxhSRfzHCcpxiEC5wvcCLUkVs73bTcnzEBC9wqC1nxok8sLPJiwKbNjoM4x881499UEkfNJHaNDR3-QDgJw0D8LQJVCI4h9OyfOI5NzJUqKEzDsNw5irxhdiYK4+JTLQWZBEEGj1Po0S8MvVyGHchzpKMmQLRcipFLESzT0Y3zwMUoLDLTMKyL45S4gEzy6KAhitLEnTUHMxLiJkJVwpkLVFOikTYtsj9VyIpyytS+StTVGQ1UPVD0L-bLNJs8TdLEYqnMkcqbS61SMJivK4qvYapKSp8xpaj02tYqLurUvrcoGgqlX+ABdAF4GcLA0E6rq-E6H44xAOp7FOc4fHsQQ0MxGhAjMdApryApyjcjyRk6GtzGUNgMhlQRnTyNg+nyHBYxJT7BG+2a6r+sZaQObTLwAAl5PGwkwBgUT3PIQdpABHBgkBKOhxRoUgYeRr7zF7d9MZBEAADk5gCfQCYcImSbJzngdB9Aabp0ZGeZ9inDZn70K52lClIaGKcl6UIbOHZnUOjR3B8DwvAadFBAAQXOEE4lXEBFdR8xHNV-z3K12lwch-WAU6D6lfRwaNG2YkQBMCGkDOWNDxkHJjtdv9ccbIWRdJ+tvA98xpfpiV8nlgFkH0HQXr6d7lbppdqzYM4hUwfQaUz9BhBuZ12IetgnpLUBvncIVWad9A9r8xuQGz2W85iFk4cEBGkYdlG0aHyuRn+8wcfy-HCeJtPyYl6naZzuXJ9vR20Y5jOV6x8w+fmQWt9F9PbCBbWx4ZieWfngPfsv7n1YxEevZ62hpUQ2IBjZSlPs7TiADdZQxhiAP2ECF7mCXrlZ++8ZZvyZpPAuyZi5SihIMeII8e6rGZKA1k5gADi+hjhwDxmqPGAAlJMndUB43eKQWh7k8aW1gJ9UgcoSh43FATQW-gAL0PoPQryQEaA7BFnTMUNVLDInoBdHIlQgA) converted a Python dict. The Python dict is given below.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```py
{'$schema': 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.8.1.json',
 'background': 'white',
 'config': {'axis': {'labelFontSize': 15,
   'labelLimit': 1000,
   'titleFontSize': 15},
  'legend': {'labelFontSize': 15, 'symbolSize': 100, 'titleFontSize': 15},
  'numberFormat': '.0f',
  'scale': {'bandPaddingInner': 0.5, 'bandPaddingOuter': 0.5},
  'style': {'bar': {'size': 20},
   'guide-label': {'fontSize': 15},
   'guide-title': {'fontSize': 15, 'value': 'asdf'}},
  'title': {'fontSize': 20, 'offset': 20}},
 'data': {'name': 'data-78d3ef908a3fe582b9e56995f5dff5f9'},
 'datasets': {'data-78d3ef908a3fe582b9e56995f5dff5f9': [{'Year': '2011',
    'counts': 1497,
    'org': 'Board',
    'percentage': 76},
   {'Year': '2011', 'counts': 78023, 'org': 'Province', 'percentage': 65},
   {'Year': '2012', 'counts': 1650, 'org': 'Board', 'percentage': 80},
   {'Year': '2012', 'counts': 80429, 'org': 'Province', 'percentage': 66},
   {'Year': '2013', 'counts': 1657, 'org': 'Board', 'percentage': 80},
   {'Year': '2013', 'counts': 82928, 'org': 'Province', 'percentage': 68},
   {'Year': '2014', 'counts': 1612, 'org': 'Board', 'percentage': 78},
   {'Year': '2014', 'counts': 84985, 'org': 'Province', 'percentage': 70},
   {'Year': '2015', 'counts': 1728, 'org': 'Board', 'percentage': 82},
   {'Year': '2015', 'counts': None, 'org': 'Province', 'percentage': None},
   {'Year': '2016', 'counts': 1844, 'org': 'Board', 'percentage': 84},
   {'Year': '2016', 'counts': 85561, 'org': 'Province', 'percentage': 72},
   {'Year': '2017', 'counts': 1984, 'org': 'Board', 'percentage': 85},
   {'Year': '2017', 'counts': 93130, 'org': 'Province', 'percentage': 74},
   {'Year': '2018', 'counts': 1950, 'org': 'Board', 'percentage': 84},
   {'Year': '2018', 'counts': 93684, 'org': 'Province', 'percentage': 75}]},
 'height': 300,
 'layer': [{'encoding': {'color': {'field': 'org',
     'title': None,
     'type': 'nominal'},
    'tooltip': [{'field': 'percentage',
      'title': 'Percentage of Students',
      'type': 'quantitative'},
     {'field': 'counts',
      'title': 'Number of Students',
      'type': 'quantitative'},
     {'field': 'org', 'title': 'level', 'type': 'nominal'}],
    'x': {'axis': {'labelAngle': 55},
     'field': 'Year',
     'title': None,
     'type': 'nominal'},
    'y': {'field': 'percentage',
     'scale': {'domain': [0, 100]},
     'title': 'Percentage of Students',
     'type': 'quantitative'}},
   'mark': {'color': 'orange', 'point': True, 'type': 'line'}},
  {'encoding': {'text': {'field': 'percentage', 'type': 'quantitative'},
    'tooltip': [{'field': 'percentage',
      'title': 'Percentage of Students',
      'type': 'quantitative'},
     {'field': 'counts',
      'title': 'Number of Students',
      'type': 'quantitative'},
     {'field': 'org', 'title': 'level', 'type': 'nominal'}],
    'x': {'field': 'Year', 'type': 'nominal'},
    'y': {'field': 'percentage', 'type': 'quantitative'}},
   'mark': {'size': 15, 'type': 'text'}}],
 'title': 'Grade 3 Reading: Overall Achievement at or above the Provincial Standard',
 'width': 300}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Altair HTMl renderer in Colab and then use the IPython display function to generate an out

```
import altair as alt
from IPython.display import display

spec = {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28}, {"a": "B", "b": 55}, {"a": "C", "b": 43},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91}, {"a": "E", "b": 81}, {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19}, {"a": "H", "b": 87}, {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}

display(alt.display.html_renderer(spec), raw=True)
```