# Vega not producing output in VS Code Jupyter notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vega-lite, vega

I am a noob in Vega and Jupyter. I'm trying to get the environment set up and I've done something wrong.

I'm able to load a dataframe and import Vega or VegaLite.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/data/cars.json')
df.head()
from vega import VegaLite
```

[image: Setup]

But when I try to create a chart I get no output or errors:

```
VegaLite({
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "Acceleration"},
    "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "Horsepower"}
  }
}, df)
```

[image: No output]

Occasionally I have gotten this:

```
c:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\vega\utils.py:51: FutureWarning: iteritems is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use .items instead. for col_name, dtype in df.dtypes.iteritems():
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem but do you know about Altair?

Comment: I'm wanting portability between Deneb in Power BI and Python. Altair looks like a different syntax.

Comment: I think you can use Altair to render your raw specs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61801180/how-to-show-vega-visualizations-in-google-colab

Comment: Just tried both methods at that link and I have the same issue. Executes fine, but no chart and no error.

Comment: I tried it on Google colab and it works fine. It must be a problem with your environment.